# How to get the location of the first and the last character of patterns in the string in r without using stringr?

Tags: r

Sample string:

`10000110`

My expected result:

`2,5,8`

The code that I used:

```
unlist(gregexpr('0',c('10000110')))
```

The result:

```
2 3 4 5 8
```

Comment: So if a start/end are the same, as in the case of `8`, the number should not be repeated?

Comment: I don't want it to be repeated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strsplit` and a loop:

```
String = c('10000110')
Index = unlist(gregexpr('0',String))
String = strsplit(String, split="")[[1]]

for(i in Index){
  if(String[i-1] != "0") message(i) #first
  if(String[i-1] == "0" & String[i+1] == "1") message(i) #last
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Changing the `gregexpr` to `0+` and then grabbing the end point via the `'match.length'` attribute:

```
x <- '10000110'
gr <- gregexpr('0+',x)
sort(union(gr[[1]], gr[[1]] + attr(gr[[1]], "match.length") - 1))
#[1] 2 5 8
```